# Why won't my .stl file show the correct information in a text editor?

Tags: graphics, blender, cad

I am quite new to work working with .stl files and in my research, I found they can be opened in a text editor where faces and vertices were clearly written out and easy to read. However, whenever I download a .stl file and open it with a text editor, I get a series of random characters. The same thing happens when I take a .blend file and export it to a .stl file. In spite of this, the .stl files still render correctly. I have attached a picture of what my problem looks like. If anyone could help me out, I would appreciate it.
Thanks.
[The random characters when I open .stl files in a text editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zpYy.jpg)

Comment: then you most likely got a [Binary STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) ...in text editor you can clearly see only ASCII STL files. Binaries are almost the same but instead of storing all the numbers as text it stores them in the native float  binary format which are much much faster to load. To read that you need to use programming or tools that convert them to ASCII version...

Comment: Ah. Did not know that. Thanks for that!